# Export UIWebView Full Content to NSData? iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

What I am trying to do is get the `UIWebView`s full content (Text, images, and CSS) in one litte package.

I figured `NSData` would be the best way to do this. Or is there another more compressed version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably late enough to respond to this, but I figured out you can get all the data from the request you made with NSCachedURLResponse as such:

```
NSCachedURLResponse* response = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] 
                                     cachedResponseForRequest:[webView request]];
NSData* data = [response data];
```

Comment: Thanks. i have done the above code to store url data in offline mode. but when i am in offline mode. i get this using NSData * sData = (NSData *)[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; than i load this data in webview [webview loadData:sData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil]; but its not working .. Can you please help me what i am doing wrong ??