# UIWebView NSURLCache load data for offline

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have seen several posts for this question and I cant figure  out how to get this working. For example, this post [NSCachedURLResponse returns object, but UIWebView does not interprets content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243913/nscachedurlresponse-returns-object-but-uiwebview-does-not-interprets-content/15253094#15253094)

suggests that we subclass and override `cachedResponseForRequest` and modify the `NSURLRequest` before returning a cached response (not sure why this needs to be done).

This is the code i have in my `NSURLCache` subclass:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {

    NSCachedURLResponse *resp = [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if (resp != nil && resp.data.length > 0) {
        NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : @"*", @"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : @"Content-Type"};
        NSHTTPURLResponse *urlresponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:request.URL statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:@"1.1" headerFields:headers];
        NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:urlresponse data:resp.data];
        return cachedResponse;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }

}
```

Now when i load the request via the webview and I'm offline, the delegate `didFailLoadWithError` gets called (it was not able to load), but before that delegate method is called, my `cachedResponseForRequest` method gets called and the cached response has some html however my `didFailLoadWithError` method still gets called. So my question is, should the `webViewDidFinishLoad` should get called if we return the cached response from the `NSURLCache`, if not how do i make this work?

I have this in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
NSUInteger cacheSizeMemory = 500*1024*1024; // 500 MB
NSUInteger cacheSizeDisk = 500*1024*1024; // 500 MB
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[CustomCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

This is the flow i want working:

1. Launch the app.
2. Hit some url (lets say slickdeals.net)
3. Go offline kill the application
4. Launch the application
5. `UIWebView` attempts to hit url but device is offline and a returned cached response is returned.
6. We display cached response.

Any thoughts on what needs to change in my code is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLCache` is designed for HTTP conform caching, and often behaves unexpectly. You must wrote your own cache for your use case, and implement a custom `NSURLProtocol` to use it. The protocol put the responses into your cache, and provides them from cache when offline. Rob Napier wrotes an [excellent article](http://robnapier.net/offline-uiwebview-nsurlprotocol) about this.